# How can I declare/ignore a missing JSX type?

Tags: typescript, jsx

I would like to use the [SVG `use` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) in a `.tsx` file:

```
<mask id="mask1">
    <use ... />
</mask>
```

I'm transpiling this to React calls directly. However, I keep receiving the following error:

> Property 'use' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

I believe this element is missing from the standard lib definitions. How can I declare this type for the TypeScript compiler to see, similar to how I can declare a class or variable? The usual `declare var` and `declare class` statements have no effect.

If that's not possible, how can I make the TypeScript compiler *ignore* this error?

Comment: Use `{/* @ts-ignore */}`. I also did a video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuiMxa8BR6o 

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you want to ignore an error inline, use this weird syntax:

```
{/* 
// @ts-ignore */}
<Foo id="fooDoesNotHaveIdType" />
```

Taken from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27552

Comment: this dose not work for me, I use @John Weisz 's workaround.

Comment: Ensure you don't add the ts-ignore like this. The extra asterisk can make it not work. 

 *// @ts-ignore */}

Comment: That is so strange. Any idea why it doesn't work if you place it on a single line?

Comment: Remove the `//` and it will work on one line in JSX. Like what basarat wrote in a different comment: `{/* @ts-ignore */}`

Answer (score 67):

I tried @Mikey's solution it did not work, but the following works for me:

```
    <Foo
      /*
      // @ts-ignore */
      id="foo does not have IdType"
      baz="foo Have bazType"
    />
```

In the above I am ignoring type error in property `id`

Comment: I was looking for attribute ignoring in `jsx`. It works for me too. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion this might be a bit risky because `baz` wouldn't get proper type-checking anymore. See: [https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49972) - don't have a solution for this yet. What do you think?

Comment: Just `/* @ts-ignore */` or `// @ts-ignore` works

Answer (score 20):

A `use` inside `mask` no longer throws a type error but if it still did today you could:

```
<mask id="mask1">
    {/* @ts-ignore */} 
    <use ... />
</mask>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `@ts-ignore`:

```
{/* @ts-ignore */} 
<mask id="mask1">
  <use ... />
</mask>
```

It also works if you use inline conditions:

```
{
  /* @ts-ignore */ myCondition && (
    <mask id="mask1">
      <use ... />
    </mask>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As of 3/20/22, the best solution to me seems to be `/* @ts-expect-error */`:

```
<ComponentWithTroublesomeProp
  okayProp={a}
  anotherOkayProp={b}
  /* @ts-expect-error */
  problematicProp={cGotTroubles}
  yetAnotherOkayProp={d}
/>
```

Judging from the [relevant GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27552), what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56913087/1927876) proposes is now out of date.

You could also try `// @ts-ignore`, but if you have `@typescript-eslint` set up, you probably have the `@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment` rule enabled, meaning you'd have to use do something like this, using two lines instead of one:

```
<ComponentWithTroublesomeProp
  okayProp={a}
  anotherOkayProp={b}
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  problematicProp={cGotTroubles}
  yetAnotherOkayProp={d}
/>
```

Comment: This is perfect for my situation, thank you. 

This has the added bonus that eslint prompts to also add a description/reason for adding the expect-error, so for example
`
          /* @ts-expect-error a descriptive reason for ignoring here */
`

Answer (score 4):

> I'm transpiling this to React calls directly

One workaround is using [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) directly:

```
<mask id="mask1">
    {React.createElement("use", { ... })}
</mask>
```

This isn't pretty, but it gets the job done, and the compiled output is essentially the same.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the solution provided by Giovanni Benussi

The [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) states that -

> A // @ts-ignore comment suppresses all errors that originate on the
> following line. It is recommended practice to have the remainder of
> the comment following @ts-ignore explain which error is being
> suppressed.

Adding the line `{/* @ts-ignore */}` before the JSX component will ignore error in the following line. Example  -

```
   {/* @ts-ignore */}
    <mask id="mask1">
      <use ... />
    </mask>
```

If you have component props defined on multiple lines and you have an issue on one of these props, then you can do the following (observe the difference) -

```
<mask id="mask1">
   <use 
      prop_one="Lets say this is ok"
      /* @ts-ignore */
      prop_two="There is a validation error"
   />
</mask>
```

Comment: How are you getting this working without making the whole set of props "ignored"? I made some testing around and wasn't able to ignore only "one line" (so one prop). It always ignores all props and leave them "unchecked". See: [https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49972) What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

`use` and other SVG elements have been added to TS's JSX definitions at the time of this writing, so the accepted answer's workaround is no longer necessary--but for anyone brought here because they need to get a custom element (web component, different UI framework, etc) working in a TSX file, follow these steps:

1. Create a `.d.ts` file. I like to put mine in the same folder as tsconfig.json
2. Add your definitions to this file, like:

   declare module JSX {
     interface IntrinsicElements {
       'some-custom-element': any;
     }
   }

The .d.ts file is automatically found by TS and then it stops complaining. I had to restart my TS server for it to pick up the changes.