# TypeScript + React | How to type check all Component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, type-safety

How can I make sure that TS is type checking all available properties of a component? The moment one property is incorrect, the rest of the "upcoming" props are not checked anymore - at least I don't see an error shown in my IDE (Webstorm).

[image]

Also see code example: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220720#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgJQKYEMDGMA0cBiArgHbbATEDCE4Fqx8AvnAGZQ1wDkUG2nAUP1QAPSLDiYKAZ3gBZAJ7VaxejABcBEmQpLIKhgB4E-OHABu6ADbAAJgAV2YDTKjBiAc36MAfHAC8cAAUYI5SAJT+vsamPDCEUMRwBt4KunSGAPTeXoIiYvCSxDJwqTR6qgBMGkSkMORUZekwRj7+QRF+USZwsfGJgd2myYOmSaXKqiOj5la2DhBgfpwW1vaOAtPTbitzjgCMU6Pbs2sLFYdZhwbj5QyHpjuni8sn82Abm6YZGXAAAjBSAC0eVQ2GBUHYUHucGOqzeB0+plhuzOcG+SUBgLgAAtUDwYfApNiIIRLDY4DJgJZLHAYNj2AB3ODoYjkokQJkgVC07HoeB04BSOAhBYwoXImwXbKfa6KRr6GDQx5vJbK9bQiXw6Ho-5AkFgvGQjXENVnKUjAyXUxhLxAA)

I encountered several "issues" or risky moments where one is using `@ts-ignore` and/or `@ts-expect-error`. It leads to false positives as it doesn't show you any error anymore although you only ignored certain ones, but indeed not all of them.

I reported a TS bug about this but it is actually intended behavior, that e.g. `@ts-expect-error` is running after all the type-checking. (see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49972)

Here the code you can try it out on your own:

```
import { React, FunctionComponent } from 'react'

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<{
  validProp: string
}> = (props) => {
  return <>MyComponent</>
}

export const MyComponent2: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyComponent
        validProp='validProp'
        invalidProp1
        invalidProp2
      />
      <MyComponent
        validProp='validProp'
        // @ts-expect-error
        invalidProp1
        invalidProp2 // <-- here it should still throw and show me that this prop is invalid
      />
      <MyComponent
        validProp='validProp'
        invalidProp1
        // @ts-expect-error
        invalidProp2
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

But, I still see issues with this. How can I make sure that TS is complaining about other wrong props although the previous incorrect prop has been ignored?

One "solution" might be only using `@ts-expect-error` at the end of all component prop definition, but how to ensure it is always ok and no-one is changing the order unintentionally so that other incorrect props are potentially ignored in the future?

I didn't find something according to my question. The only topic I found is this. But also here, the problems are still present, so I can actually not really agree with those solutions provided there.
[How can I declare/ignore a missing JSX type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245257/how-can-i-declare-ignore-a-missing-jsx-type)

Where can I improve?
Is this a limitation that I can't work around?