# How to use popover with React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, popover

I am Trying to use HTML popover with React & typescript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/popover

```jsx
function AlertWindow() {
  return (
    <>
      <button popovertarget='my-popover'>Open Popover</button>
      <div popover id='my-popover'>
        Greetings, one and all!
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

React shows some error

```
Type '{ children: string; popovertarget: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Property 'popovertarget' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
```

and

```
Type '{ children: string; popover: true; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'popover' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
```

How can I fix this?

This is the `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "app.ts"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the packages I am using for this project `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "quick-pkt",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "gp": "tsc && vite build --config vite.config.gp.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview --host",
    "prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "prettier-write": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "emoji-store": "^1.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-lazy-with-preload": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "swiper": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the [Popover API](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/introducing-popover-api/) is too new. Your best bet is to raise an issue at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues). In the meantime, you'll want to get Typescript to [ignore unknown props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56913087/283366)